# Hover CSS for an image type drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

### Background

I am creating a drop-down menu that shows Asia region.
Each part of the image should redirect the user to a specified link.

### Effects wanted to Reach

When the user put their mouse over the region, the image should be changed to orange.

### Images

Normal State (newmenu.png)

[image: Normal State]

Hover State (newmenu_hover.png)

[image: Hover State]

### Method trying to Accomplish

It will take a while if I cut the image into 8 small pieces. So I decided to use CSS `background-position` to finish that.

---

### Problem

As the following image. All links show blue China.
When I put an mouse over it, it will changed to orange China.

```css
#newmenu {
  line-height: 24px;
}

#newmenu a:link, #newmenu a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/5e185e55196d23e27ebb99c4a0b55909.png);
}

#newmenu a:hover, #newmenu a:active {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/48bd4dd0bb862be01d047f4d38296e4e.png);
}

#newmenu .newmenu_china {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#newmenu .newmenu_hongkong {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 24px;
}

#newmenu .newmenu_macau {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 48px;
}

#newmenu .newmenu_singapore {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 72px;
}

<hr>

## Problems ##

As shown in the following image. All links show blue China.<br>
When I put my mouse onto it, it will changed to orange China.

[![Problem][3]][3]

<hr>

## Source Code (background-url edited) ##
```

```html
<div class="downmenu" id="newmenu">
  <a href="./china.php" id="newmenu_china" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./hongkong.php" id="newmenu_hongkong" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./macau.php" id="newmenu_macau" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./singapore.php" id="newmenu_singapore" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id for the links are ID, so you just have to edit the CSS

```css
#newmenu {
  line-height: 24px;
}

#newmenu a:link, #newmenu a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/5e185e55196d23e27ebb99c4a0b55909.png);
}

#newmenu a:hover, #newmenu a:active {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/48bd4dd0bb862be01d047f4d38296e4e.png);
}

#newmenu #newmenu_china {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_hongkong {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 24px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_macau {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 48px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_singapore {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 72px;
}

<hr>
```

```html
<div class="downmenu" id="newmenu">
  <a href="./china.php" id="newmenu_china" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./hongkong.php" id="newmenu_hongkong" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./macau.php" id="newmenu_macau" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="./singapore.php" id="newmenu_singapore" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: OK I made a stupid mistake though. So thanks everyone who noticed me. You guys are great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change `CSS` as follows, you should use `id` selector

```css
#newmenu {
  line-height: 24px;
}

#newmenu a:link, #newmenu a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/5e185e55196d23e27ebb99c4a0b55909.png);
}

#newmenu a:hover, #newmenu a:active {
  display: block;
  width: 183px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/48bd4dd0bb862be01d047f4d38296e4e.png);
}

#newmenu #newmenu_china {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_hongkong {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 24px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_macau {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 48px;
}

#newmenu #newmenu_singapore {
  height: 24px;
  background-position: 0px 72px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in css You have to use id selector.

For example :

You use `#newmenu .newmenu_hongkong` instead `#newmenu_hongkong`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML uses ids while CSS uses classes. That is why background-position property is not applied to the elements.

Answer (score 1):

simply add hover effect in all `newmenu_china`, `newmenu_hongkong`, vise versa like this

```
#newmenu_china:hover {
  background-color: #FFA500;
}
```

and yes you should use id selector `#`

Hope this helps